Unable to access a folder in different layers in a docker image
I'm trying to build a Java image and I'm using cache mounts to speed up subsequent dependency installations.
Here is my Dockerfile :
FROM eclipse-temurin:17-jdk-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY mvnw .
COPY .mvn .mvn
COPY src src

RUN --mount=type=bind,src=pom.xml,target=pom.xml \
    --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.m2 \
    ./mvnw install -DskipTests && \
    ls -a /root/ # prints .m2 folder

RUN ls -a /app/target # prints the content of generated target folder 

RUN ls -a /root/ # prints no file

As I know maven's install command creates a target folder and downloads the dependencies from remote maven repository and caches them to /root/.m2 folder. The thing is I can access this folder in the first RUN layer but can't access in the third RUN layer.
I tried to containerize this image and search for ".m2" folder in it by "find / -type d -name ".m2" but it also prints nothing.

RUN --mount options are specific to a single RUN command.  In the later RUN command, nothing is mounted.

@DavidMaze but how the target folder can be accessible in subsequent run layers but .m2 folder cannot. maven populates .m2 folder's content during dependency installation.is this folder only generated in this layer, if so why? I can copy .m2 folder's content to a shared directory  and use it in different layers, but I don't understand the docker mechanism.

You don't RUN --mount anything over /app or /app/target, so the build output goes into the image filesystem as normal.

thanks @DavidMaze I think I completely misunderstood this concept.
